# ScreenOS SSG-320M Source Interface Based Routing

Tags: firewall, routing, dhcp-server, juniper, screenos

quick question. Couldn't figure this out with even the ScreenOS Bible.

Juniper SSG-320M Firewall, Just added an 8port PIM Module(ETH1/0 to 1/7):
ETH0/0(Trust) 172.16.1.1/16
ETH0/2(UnTrust) 192.168.0.5/24

Just added the 8 port PIM Ethernet card, assigned it to Trust Zone but can't figure out how to route traffic coming ETH1/0 thru ETH1/7 over to the rest of the 172.16.1.1/16 subnet.

It would be perfect case scenario if I could just have everything in the Trust zone be in the 172.16.x.x/16 subnet. Have tried all combination of Virtual Routers/Source Interface routing, etc. Ideas? Am I missing something totally basic?!

Also, on a kinda-related note. The ETH0/0(Trust 172.16.1.1/16) is a DHCP server, serves ip's just fine to that interface. Is it possible to have the add-on cards (ETH1/0 thru ETH1/7) also be DHCP clients? So if a cable is plugged into the add-on card, it receives DHCP address from the ETH0/0 Trusted DHCP server handing out 172.16.1.x IP's?

Comment: Anybody?!? Bump!

Answer (score 0):

Think I came up with the answer. Just add all the ports to a VLAN and tag.